# Is there a way to convert currency on a website based on User Locale

Tags: javascript, localization

I have implemented the locale on my web application and it works fine. But there is one hurdle in finishing the project -- CURRENCY!! Depending on the language the currency and its value is also supposed to change. So lets say currently language is English and currency is $ - Dollar now when I select a different language lets say Chinese then every text on the website changes because of the locale plug-in but I want the currency to change as well. I dont want to call the store again to fetch new data. So is it possible to do that using JavaScript and any existing plug-in or modification in locale plug-in

Comment: Without fetching new data? How you want to convert $10,000 to €?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski At present the way I change the language is my executing Ux.locale.Manager.updateLocale('fr') or Ux.locale.Manager.updateLocale('en') So this does not actually call the store for new data, so similarly I would like to change the currency now I know this involves some calculation, So I was wondering if I can create my own CurrencyField and then override the SetLocacle function in it. Something like that. But I am not able to put a finger on it.